# while using OnEachRow it not rollback entries from second table if database error occur laravel excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

#### if their error comes it rollback the entries from the first table. but it does not roll back the entries from the second table.

#### Can anyone guide how it is possible?

#### what my case.

#### if their error comes it rollback the entries from the agent table. but it does not roll back the entries from the payment table.

> To create this error I hardcoded the value for the third row and set the status value to null. but status only takes an integer value why it creates the error.

> it gives an error  Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'status'
> but it rollback entries form agent table but not from payment table

```
class noteImport implements OnEachRow {

    public function onRow(Row $row){
        $row = $row->toArray();
        
            $Option = [
            "firstpay" => 1,
            "amount" => 1,
            "payment_type" => 1,
            "info" => "1",
            "enter_date" => date('y/m/d'),
            "recieve_date" => date('y/m/d'),
            "status" => $row['srno'] != 3 ? 1 : "",     
            ];

            $agent = Agent::create([
            "agent_code" => "1",
            "name" => "1",
            "address" => "1",
            "phone" => 454,
            "password" => "asd",
            "upload" => "1",
            "status" => 1,
            ]);

        $agent->payment()->create($Option);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to explain what you are trying to achieve. Right now, you're in the middle of your problem and explained that problem. Start from the beginning. Then ... when "status" needs to be an integer, try to cast it to an integer. `"status" => (int) $row['srno'] != 3 ? 1 : "",`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. actually, I want to handle the error if something gets wrong like that while importing it should delete entries from both tables.

I just create this issue to understand the concept. I trying to explain. I have no issue with typecast.

there is a problem if this type of error happens it deletes. It deletes records from the first(agent) table but not the second(payment) table.